# What parts of google chrome are not open source? why?

Tags: google-chrome

What parts of google chrome are not open source? why?

Comment: By definition, you can't really know what is *NOT* open source.

Comment: *None* of Google Chrome is open source. You may be thinking about the portions that are released as [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/)?

Comment: @Cody Gray: those portions are part of Google Chrome, so "none" is a bad description.  Still off-topic, though.

Comment: @Wooble: It's a perfectly valid description. Google has explicitly retained *all* rights to Google Chrome: it is not open source under any definition. You're assuming that an object is the sum of its parts, which is a bit too simplistic both in legal and practical terms.